# Does Apple Family sharing notify the organizer when a member leaves the unit?

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, apple-id

When you leave family sharing on iPhone does the organizer get a notification that you have left family sharing?

Answer (score 1):

Yes - both parties get a notification and possibly a mail, too.